# Using Spring @Value annotation for multiple properties

Tags: java, spring

I'm using @Value annotation to inject properties and now the properties have increased and the constructor is getting really big .Is there a way to handle this problem

```
@Component
public class Job {

    private String someProperty

    @Autowired
    public Job(@Value("${some.property}") String someProperty,.............){
        this.someProperty = someProperty
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just annotate the fields directly.

```
@Value("${some.property}") 
private String someProperty
```

You can do any additional processing in a `@PostConstruct` method.

Comment: writing a unit test is easy If I use constructor . I can do `Job job = new Job("fakeSomeProperty");`..

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just do this:

```
@Component public class Job {

@Value("${some.property1}") private String someProperty1
@Value("${some.property2}") private String someProperty2
//...

@Autowired public Job( ){ 


// your someProperty1 is already set
}
```

Comment: ok so someProperty1 gets initialized when an instance of class is created?

Comment: yes, those values will be initialized by Spring at startup of the application. I assume that you will get an instance of this class using @Autowired .